# script to append to file on a specific condition not working -Python script

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to Python and trying to write a script to append into a file if the oracle Golden Gate group Process is not listed in one of the other existing file. But looks like "if condition" seems to be not working its appending everything from file f3 into f4. Please any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
enter code 
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime

os.environ[ 'GG_HOME' ] = '/oraadm/ogg18.1/'
sys.stdout = open('GG_Status.log','a')
GGPATH = os.environ.get('GG_HOME')
os.chdir(GGPATH)
os.system('echo info all |./ggsci >> ./dirpyth/GG_Status.log')
print("\n")
sys.stdout=Restore_Point
f1 = open(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/GG_Status.log','r')
f2 = open(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/GG_Running_Process.txt','w+')
f3 = open(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/gginfo.obey','a+')
f4 = open(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/mgr1.prm','a+')
os.system("cat /oraadm/ogg18.1/dirpyth/GG_Status.log |grep -E 'EXTRACT|REPLICAT'|awk '{print $3}'|sort > /oraadm/ogg18.1/dirpyth/GG_Running_Process.txt")

a=f2.read().splitlines()

for i in a:
    if not i in f3.read():
        f3.write("info " + (i) + "\n")

f3.close()
f3 = open(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/gginfo.obey','r')

a=f3.read().splitlines()

os.system('cp /oraadm/ogg18.1/dirpyth/mgr1.prm /oraadm/ogg18.1/dirpyth/mgr1_`(date +"%m-%d-%y")`.prm')

for i in a:
    b=(i).replace('info','')
    print(b)
    if b in f4.read():
        pass
    elif  b[1]=='E' or b[1]=='P':
             f4.write("AUTOSTART EXTRACT" + (i.replace('info','')) + "\n")
    else:
        f4.write("AUTOSTART REPLICAT " + (i.replace('info','')) + "\n")
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
f4.close()
#print(f3.readline())

#os.system('echo -e "Below GG Processes are Abended:\n============================\n`date`:\n\n" "`cat /oraadm/ogg18.1/dirpyth/GG_Abended.log`"|mailx -s "GG Process Status- `hostname`" xxxxx@xxxx.org')

os.remove(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/GG_Status.log')
#os.remove(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/GG_Running_Process.txt')
#os.remove(GGPATH + '/dirpyth/gginfo.obey')
```

Comment: Hi monto, welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you call `f3.read()` which returns the full file in the variable, do you not want to have `f3.read().splitlines()` there as well?

Comment: Thanks.That piece of code has been commented.

Comment: Please need help with this.